# Forward with masking but gives the same domain name even redirect to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, cross-domain

I have subscribed a domain from `Godaddy.com`. When I make forward with masking for my IP to my domain then it remain as the domain name not like what I want as expected.

For example, I have an IP like below:

`18.220.xxx.xxx`

I do forward with masking to my IP like:

`www.mydomain.com`

The current output when I click any page on my system, the page always go to same domain name for example if I want go to about-us page, then it should go to `www.mydomain.com/about-us`. The page was finely redirect to the place but the address was still the same like `www.mydomain.com`.

When I view page source, they use `iframe` to merge with my IP.

---

How I can get the output like

```
www.mydomain.com/about-us
www.mydomain.com/contact-us
...
...
etc
```

Anyone can help me? The problems come since I subscribe `AWS` and I subscribe the domain in `godaddy.com` separately.

Any helps offered would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to point the domain by changing the advanced dns to your server. URL forwarding is not the right way to do it

Comment: So how I can fix this? Can you show me.

Comment: You get your ip for your server, then go into the domain management and edit the A records to point to that IP address.

Comment: is it A(host) ?

Comment: Sorry, I'am quite confuse with the settings.

Comment: @Rasclatt, I found this link...https://my.godaddy.com/help/add-an-a-record-19238
..I will try first  thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah, you have one host as `www` then points to `18.220.xxx.xxx` and the ttl as `7200`, then do a new one where host is `@` then same points ip and ttl, then `*` for the host, then same for the others. Then turn off url forwarding, that will mess up the DNS

Comment: How to remove www? Last one..huhu..the last steps working properly!

Comment: I hate `www` huhu

Comment: If you want to remove any of them there should be a delete button to remove one.

Comment: Alright then. Tq very much!